# I'm connected to wifi but cannot access the internet except thru VPN (14.04)

Tags: 14.04, internet, vpn, browser

I've had 14.04 for a while now and love it. The other day, out of the blue, I cannot load pages through any of my browsers or other programs unless I am connected to my VPN. All other machines in the house can connect, it's only this one laptop. I've searched the internet for answers and have found some, but all the fixes I find are for Windows. Is there a way to fix this, Ubuntu style?

I have tried connecting with the ethernet cable in addition to wifi and the same thing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Lux,

I almost hate to answer because I'm not sure that I have the solution. I did a little research and found something interesting here:

https://superuser.com/questions/713977/how-to-prevent-firefox-from-connecting-to-the-internet-through-vpn

What the above answer suggests is making sure that you haven't, or an application hasn't, created static routes that might be forcing your machine to go through the vpn for connectivity.

To check, go to your network connections (I'm guessing you're using IPv4), select the IPv4, find where you can add/edit static routes. If there are any (you might want to be cautious here and jot down the information, in case you need to put it back in) remove them.

After that, I would clear the cache an history on the browser, reboot, and try again.